# Are Quincy Christian?

Tags: bleach

A lot of Quincy objects look crosses, and a number of their attacks reference holy things. For example, there is an attack called "Quincy Vollstandig" which, at least according to the translation I was reading, translated to "Complete Holy Form". Are Quincy as a group Christian (or some other religion) or are these names because they sound cool rather than having any particular meaning?

Comment: they seem to act anime-typical Christian since they didn't believe in purifying Hollows but rather destroying them, in a lot of supernatual anime i've seen the Christian Church has always been that anything demon or anything like a demon is to be destroyed regardless

Comment: Well it is more like the pseudo-christian religion. also as a sidenote, "Vollständig" simply means "complete" in german, there is no particular religious meaning to it.

Answer (score 5):

[Religion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Religion) is an organized collection of beliefs, cultural systems, and world views that relate humanity to the supernatural, and to spirituality.

While it would a stretch to say combating Hollows might be an extension of Quincy culture, it doesn't hold through with a belief system. Religion by definition requires belief, a viewpoint with intangible evidence. When evidence becomes tangible, it holds at least some quantifiable fact.

For Quincy, harnessing spiritual particles to shoot projectiles of energy and the dangers of Hollows interacting with the real world are both instances of fact.

There has been no mention of religion or specifically Christianity in Bleach, but despite either existing, the Quincy are more of a clan of warriors or hunters. I understand the suggestive designs that seem Religion-based but I believe it's to appeal to an exorcist fanbase as a supernatural character option in this story about ghosts, good or bad, and their governors.

Source(s): [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Religion)

Comment: In chapter 508, at least in the English translation I read, the Vandereich king mentions "the light of God". Is this supposed to be just sort of a generic "we have something standing behind us"?

Comment: @kuwaly Basically, yes. The Sankt Zwinger translates to Santa Kennel which can roughly be presumed Saint (Holy) Shelter if you get particular. It just seems like a Quincy meme to be intimidating through divination.

Comment: But the story's not over. There's a Soul King. Maybe there's more to Yhwach (the Vandereich king)'s beliefs than seen thus far.

Answer (score 0):

No such thing has been specified by the author. Think of it as a cult or clan if you like, but all we know is that their clothes, weapons and name of attacks are due to the their traditions and history (which we don't completely know about just yet).